# Bianary Search algorithm comparisons

Tags: python, algorithm, comparison

I created a python program that sorts a list of numbers by using a binary search algorithm, but now i need to include a comparisons counter that counts the number of comparisons it made. I am struggling to figure out where to put the counters because I get errors in the test code given to me or with my program itself.

[heres my code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFF5x.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On Stack Overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see [*How do I format my code blocks?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186). A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you have tri

Answer (score 0):

since you already set comparisons as global variable, you don't need to return comparisons in your function actually.

instead, just after your `global comparisons`, put

```
comparisons += 1
```

will be enough.
and in the end of your program, `print(comparisons)`